# One time URL for download of cloud storage objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wanna generate a signed URL to download some objects from storage, and after first click, the URL should be invalid (one time link)

Comment: I think you cannot. By [definition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview), Signed URLs "... provides limited permission **and** time to make a request.". I think there's no way to expire this after e.g. a single upload.

Comment: A buddy wrote [Limiting file size and content (type) using Signed URLs](https://blog.salrashid.dev/articles/2022/limit_gcs_signedurl/) perhaps it's possible that you could constrain your users by some known unit file size.... If you expect them to upload a single 50MB document, use Sal's trick to limit the upload size to 51MB

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Storage does not support this feature.

This type of limitation is very difficult to implement in the real world. With retries, parallel downloads, etc. a single click limitation would turn into a major pain and failure for clients.

For companies that do provide this feature, they have special software that downloads and notifies their servers of success. Their servers manage everything.